# How to hide and show two buttons in angular

Tags: angularjs

When I click funone button, funtwo button needs to show and funone needs to get hidden.

Then when I click funtwo button,  funone should show and funtwo should hide. How can I hide funtwo button in this case, funtwo button already has `ng-hide="true"`?

here is the html:

```
<button ng-click="funone()" ng-hide="hidefunone" ng-show="showfunone"> funone </button>

<button ng-click="funtwo()" ng-hide="true" ng-show="showfuntwo">  funtwo </button>
```

here is the angular:

```
  $scope.funone = function(){
    $scope.showfuntwo = true;
    $scope.hidefunone=  true;
  }

  $scope.funtwo = function(){
   $scope.showfunone = true;
  }
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to use both `ng-show` and `ng-hide` on the same element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a single method and boolean as shown below:

```js
$scope.first = false;
$scope.toggle = function() {
  $scope.first = !$scope.first;
}
```

```html
<button ng-click="toggle()" ng-hide="first">funone</button>
<button ng-click="toggle()" ng-hide="!first">funtwo</button>
```

Comment: Thanks all. This is pretty close to what I implemented in the end.

Answer (score 4):

I'd simplify the whole thing down to two states based on a single Boolean model `state`

```
<button ng-click="state = true" ng-hide="state"> funone </button>
<button ng-click="state = false" ng-show="state"> funtwo </button>
```

Plunker ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/GF1eNm6O7U0i34HQPhwb?p=preview

Just keep in mind that `ng-show` and `ng-hide` do the same thing but just act on the inverse model value.